# Drake build from source stubgen failed

Tags: cmake, build, bazel, robotics, drake

I'm building drake from source, specifically this branch of Russ' fork:
https://github.com/RussTedrake/drake

everything worked without issue until the last command `make -j`

where I get the following output:

```
[ 12%] Performing build step for 'drake_cxx_python'
INFO: Analyzed target //:install (0 packages loaded, 0 targets configured).
INFO: Found 1 target...
ERROR: /Users/chewchiashaoyuan/Documents/Software/drake/bindings/pydrake/BUILD.bazel:780:22: GenerateMypyStubs bindings/pydrake/pydrake/__init__.pyi failed: (Exit 1): stubgen failed: error executing command bazel-out/darwin-opt/bin/bindings/pydrake/stubgen --quiet '--package=pydrake' '--output=bazel-out/darwin-opt/bin/bindings/pydrake'

Use --sandbox_debug to see verbose messages from the sandbox and retain the sandbox build root for debugging
Matplotlib created a temporary config/cache directory at /var/folders/sl/37m0k__51_3_5c5j02w201r40000gn/T/matplotlib-8mr5qkfg because the default path (/Users/chewchiashaoyuan/.matplotlib) is not a writable directory; it is highly recommended to set the MPLCONFIGDIR environment variable to a writable directory, in particular to speed up the import of Matplotlib and to better support multiprocessing.
Critical error during semantic analysis: /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pydrake/symbolic.pyi:203: error: invalid syntax
Target //:install failed to build
Use --verbose_failures to see the command lines of failed build steps.
ERROR: /Users/chewchiashaoyuan/Documents/Software/drake/BUILD.bazel:63:8 Middleman _middlemen/install-runfiles failed: (Exit 1): stubgen failed: error executing command bazel-out/darwin-opt/bin/bindings/pydrake/stubgen --quiet '--package=pydrake' '--output=bazel-out/darwin-opt/bin/bindings/pydrake'

Use --sandbox_debug to see verbose messages from the sandbox and retain the sandbox build root for debugging
INFO: Elapsed time: 9.617s, Critical Path: 9.33s
INFO: 2 processes: 2 internal.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully
make[2]: *** [drake_cxx_python-prefix/src/drake_cxx_python-stamp/drake_cxx_python-build] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/drake_cxx_python.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

My operating system is:
macOS Monterey Version 12.6

The full `make -j -d` output is [here](https://pastebin.com/SmambLkv)

I referenced https://drake.mit.edu/from_source.html, https://drake.mit.edu/bazel.html#snopt and https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/issues/12175
I did the following:

```
git clone https://github.com/RussTedrake/drake
cd drake
git checkout kin_traj_opt2
./setup/mac/install_prereqs.sh
cd ..
mkdir drake-build
cd drake-build
cmake -DWITH_ROBOTLOCOMOTION_SNOPT=ON ../drake
make -j
```

Fixes attempted:
tried deleting the whole drake-build directory and doing the whole process from scratch, got the same errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One filename from the error message stands out: `/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pydrake/symbolic.pyi`. It looks like you have `sudo pip install drake` installed into a system-wide directory. That is likely interfering with the from-source build of Drake and will need to be removed.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Unfortunately I stupidly installed macOS Ventura (13) and now I can't test your suggested fix... 

ERROR: Skipping '//:install': no such package '@python//': could not determine macOS version: unsupported macOS '13'

Any thoughts as to how I might work around this? If not I have another machine that has Ubuntu 20.04 and I might just try to work off that...

Comment: Something like https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/pull/18210.

Comment: Hi! I'm once again trying to install the python bindings. The macOS Ventura (13) errors are no longer making the build fail. I did have drake installed via pip, I uninstalled it as you suggested but am still getting the exact same error any thoughts on what I should try? Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: I don't see how you're getting the "exact same error"?  The prior error mentioned `/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pydrake/symbolic.pyi`, but you said that you un-installed it so that file shouldn't exist anymore.

Comment: Ok this issue has been resolved thanks for your help! I had previously done pip uninstall and checked pip list to verify that pydrake was gone but there was still a pydrake folder in `/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages`. I deleted this folder and then `make -j` worked without errors. Thanks for your help and patience!